# Way to number and sort articles in articles plugin in TikiWiki

Tags: sorting, plugins, tiki-wiki

I'm using articles plugin for joining my articles into one wiki page, but i need a way to number them and sort them. I know, that article plugin have order param, but if you have 100 articles, it's not posible to write their id in good order.

I thing sort is better option. So, there is my question. Can you make addonal parameter for article, that is invisible and you can use it in sort atribute of articles plugin? Or maybe easier way, can you us heading of article for sort atribute of articles plugin?

Comment: This is wierd! As TikiWiki documentation is saying, i can sort by subtitle, topline, etc. But the working one for me is Title and authorName... Nothing ever can be to easy...

Answer (score 0):

I am worried, I do not 100% understand your question.

In the articles plugin you can filter the articles by topic, type, category.

Articles are sorted by publishing date - not by iD number.

You can use pagination, tags, search etc. to browse articles.

When you list articles in the admin dialogue, I am sure the list is sortable and aswell sortable by Id number.

Are you asking for another feature (parameter) to optionally sort articles in the wikiplugin by Id? If that is not existing, you might want to hire a coder who get you this for a low fee. You might have a chance to find contactto one of the coders in the developer list of the Tiki community. But I am not sure, it it made even sense to commit this in the upstream.
Sorry for saying this way, but as said, I am not sure, if I understand it right.

Anyway, 
best regards,
Torsten